# Which IDE is best for iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, eclipse, xcode, netbeans, ide

I'm going to develop an iPhone application.

Which IDE is the best, Eclipse or Netbeans?

Comment: Are you planning to develop in Java? The native development environment is XCode, apple's own IDE.

Comment: there is only one IDE you can develop native applications for the iPhone, and that is Xcode on an OSX machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**Xcode**](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/) is *the* IDE for iOS and Mac OS X development.

Use it, love it, live it.

Oh, and you can't use any other IDE to develop for these platforms.

Comment: `s/quintessential//`

Comment: `s/love it/hate it/` Visual Studio and Eclipse are far better.

Comment: Currently there is an other IDE to develop for iOS next to Xcode: AppCode from JetBrains. Check it out, it's nice!

Answer (score 3):

The best IDE for iOS Development is still Apples XCode. You cannot use Eclipse or Netbeans.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant Android, not iPhone. For Android you can develop either in Eclipse or Netbeans, the most popular one being Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

If you find you do not like XCode, you could have a look at MonoTouch (http://monotouch.net/) which allows you to write iPhone applications in C# instead of Objective C.

Note:  Costs money, but might be worth it if you are on a tight schedule.